# WSO2 API MANAGER - How to get endpoint with mediator

Tags: wso2

How can i get the endpoint production or sandbox url in customsequence?

Or how can i use two payload factories in the same customsequence using the endpoint saved in the api manager publisher?

For example, i have a custom sequence that made a call in the same endpoint, returning different data:

```
<payloadFactory description="" media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <ser:users xmlns:ser="http://service.test.com">
            <arg0 xmlns="">$1</arg0>
        </ser:users>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg value="user" />
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
<call blocking="true">
    <endpoint>
        <address format="soap11" uri="http://url_soap?wsdl"/>
    </endpoint>
</call>
<property expression="//return/text()" name="token" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:x="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
```

Thanks

[printscreen urls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7gWO.png)